# Public Type (VB) para Java

Tags: java, visual-basic-6

Tenho um projeto que roda em vb e tenho que passar para Java, em certa parte tenho as declarações de estrutura. Minha pergunta é: Qual a melhor maneira de fazer isto em Java, sem perda de desempenho?

Os arquivos que tenho de ler são grandes e serão salvos em SQL, não posso mandar diretamente, pois tenho de tratar os dados, mas penso que criar um objeto pra cada estrutura seja muito pesado.

Exemplo:

```vb
Public Type defItemVendidoComp
   data                        As Date
   Hora                        As String * 8
   NumeroPDV                   As Integer
   TipoTransacao               As Byte
   Sequencial                  As Long
   NumeroCupom                 As Long
   Operador                    As String * 6
   CodigoAutomacao             As Double
   DigitoAutomacao             As Byte
   CodigoInterno               As Double
   DigitoInterno               As Byte    
   Peso                        As Single
   PesoMin                     As Single
   PesoMax                     As Single
   Tolerancia                  As Single 
End Type
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O mais "próximo" do Type do VB serão classes em java (que é a mesma coisa que classes no VB). Algo ainda próximo do Type seria você criar uma classe com atributos públicos, mas mesmo assim você ainda teria que instanciar ela, ex:

```
public class MeuType {
    public Date data;
    public String hora;
    public Integer NumeroPDV;
    ...
}

MeuType meuType = new MeuType();
meuType.data = new Date();
meuType.hora = "11:00:00";
meuType.NumeroPDV = 3;
```

Para ler arquivos grandes, sempre use qualquer classe que use internamente BufferedReader para garantir leitura buferizada. Se você já estiver familiarizado com Java, a lib [commons-io](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/) já possui uma infinidade de métodos utilitários que provavelmente você iria fazer que usam internamente BufferedReader.